# Ragged2e Parfillskip Stretch

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, ragged2e, glue, parfillskip

The `ragged2e` package uses the default length `0pt plus 1fil` for the parameter `\RaggedRightParfillskip` I've tested replacing this value with `0pt plus \textwidth` and I've observed that LaTeX will sometimes move words/fragments from the right edge to the last line.
Two questions:
(1) I'm not sure why this is the case. I feel like the `\textwidth` and `1fil` are essentially the same measurement because they both completely fill the line.
(2) Is there a difference between the `\RaggedRightParfillskip` lengths `0pt plus \textwidth` and `0pt plus (any length greater than \textwidth)` e.g. `0pt plus 2\textwidth`? I'm curious whether in general using a stretch length that is greater than the current line length will bug/glitch (e.g. in smaller line lengths in a parbox, minipage, itemized/enumerated lists, etc.).

Comment: Even though `1fil` and `\textwidth` can potentially be the same width, the important difference is that `1fil` is not exact.  Thus the internal calculations are not identical, leading to the differences you see.  I can't predict the exact implications, but am not surprised by what you report.  Using an exact dimension larger than the actual width, as might happen in a `\parbox` or `minipage`, sounds like asking for problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big difference between `plus \textwidth`  and `plus 1fil`.

The second is infinite so any finite stretch on the line will be ignored, and in particular interword white space will be set to normal size.

The first is finite so is accumulated with all other finite stretch on the line and all such spaces stretch in proportion. So inter-word spaces on the last line will be stretched if the `\parfillskip` needs to be more than zero

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
1
One two three four five. One two three four five.
One two three four five. One two three four five.
One two three four five. One two three four fivexxxxx.
a a a a a a a.


\parfillskip=0pt plus \textwidth
2
One two three four five. One two three four five.
One two three four five. One two three four five.
One two three four five. One two three four fivexxxxx.
a a a a a a a.


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Your 2nd question has essentially the same answer. If you use `2\textwidth` stretch the proportion of the total finite stretch made up by inter-word spaces is reduced, so the inter-word space will stretch less and the end of line space will stretch more compared to using `1\textwidth`

Comment: The original post did not explicitly ask "why do line breaks end up being different", but I think it is worth to explain that too: as pointed out by David Carlisle, 1fil means "infinite strechability". This means that, even if the last line of the paragraph is very small, it never adds any badness to the total badness/demerits of the paragraph. With \textwidth, the space at the end of the last line is ideally zero and any stretching will add some badness (although not a lot), so TeX will slightly prefer to format the paragraph with a longer last line.